# Какой из массивов будет правильно записан в поток?

Tags: массивы, delphi

Статический и динамический массивы сохраняются в поток следующим образом:

```
var
  A: array[0..999] of Integer;
  B: array of Integer;

Stream.WriteBuffer(A, Length(A) * SizeOf(Integer));
Stream.WriteBuffer(B, Length(B) * SizeOf(Integer));
```

Какой из массивов будет правильно записан в поток? (Считаем, что массив B на момент исполнения этого кода должным образом инициализирован.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Stream.WriteBuffer(A[0], SizeOf(A[0]) * Length(A));
Stream.WriteBuffer(B[0], SizeOf(B[0]) * Length(B));
```

Comment: Получается, ни один из массивов по условиям задачи не будет записан правильно в поток?

Comment: Так не интересно. По условиям твоей задачи правильно запишется только статический массив. А вообще, сам протестируй.

Comment: Если динамический, то [SetLength][1].


  [1]: http://www.delphibasics.ru/SetLength.php

Comment: Спасибо тебе! Обязательно протестирую. =)

Comment: Виталина, тоже спасибо за редактирование, я здесь просто новенький )